# Remove an object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrayobject

What is the way to remove an property named "itemType"from the below given object
?

```
 {
    "id": 19,
    "cost": 10,
    "items": 10,
    "numbers": 10,
    "status": false,
    "hours": 10,
    "itemType": {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "PC 350",
        "description": "PC 350"        
    },
    "typeid": 12
}
```

So that the final array should look like

```
 {
    "id": 19,
    "cost": 10,
    "items": 10,
    "numbers": 10,
    "status": false,
    "hours": 10,         
    "typeid": 12
}
```

Comment: there is no array here, and no object `itemtype`. There is however a single object that has a property `itemtype`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove property from JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/remove-property-from-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `object` not `array`. You can use `delete` like this

```
   var obj = {
        "id": 19,
        "cost": 10,
        "items": 10,
        "numbers": 10,
        "status": false,
        "hours": 10,
        "itemType": {
            "id": 16,
            "name": "PC 350",
            "description": "PC 350"        
        },
        "typeid": 12
    }

    delete obj.itemType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is an object and you want to delete a property from it, or you have an array and want to delete a  value, the way to delete is -

```
delete obj.itemType //object.
delete array[3] //delete 4th item from the array.
```

Note - the structure you have provided is not an array, its an object.

Comment: Then what can be the best solution @charlietfl?

Comment: splice() . Using delete doesn't remove that index, so length doesn't change. Try this `var a=[1,2,3];
delete a[1]
console.log(a.length);`

Comment: True, use splice method which is the preferred way.

Comment: Pls not using delete would leave the index as it is and accessing it would give you undefined. Where as splice is going to remove the  required element and automatically shift the values.